# Composer using old package information

Tags: composer-php

I am trying to install this package: https://github.com/dachcom-digital/pimcore-formbuilder

When I do so composer strangely uses much older version of package information in `composer.json` (https://github.com/dachcom-digital/pimcore-formbuilder/blob/96ab9de/composer.json) while ignoring master.

How can I solve this?
What I tried to do is this without any luck:

`composer cache-clear`

`composer require dachcom-digital/pimcore-formbuilder --prefer-source`

Update, full output:

```
> rm -rf ~/.composer/cache
> composer clear-cache
Clearing cache (cache-dir): /Users/paveldubinin/.composer/cache
Cache directory does not exist (cache-files-dir): 
Cache directory does not exist (cache-repo-dir): 
Cache directory does not exist (cache-vcs-dir): 
All caches cleared.
> ~/composertest  composer require dachcom-digital/members:dev-master --prefer-source
./composer.json has been created
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Package operations: 1 install, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Installing dachcom-digital/members (dev-master 4a80071) Cloning 4a80071560 from cache
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
```

Comment: Can you please show the output that you get when running the `require` command?

Comment: @xabbuh thanks for checking, please see my updated question with full log

Comment: I am not sure what you mean then because `4a80071560` indeed seems to be the latest commit on the `master` branch: https://github.com/dachcom-digital/pimcore-members/commits/master

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so they changed package name on packagist:

`dachcom-digital/pimcore-formbuilder` -> `dachcom-digital/formbuilder`

but repo on github is still the same, so it was confusing.